# php file_get_contents and &amp;

Tags: php

I'm trying to use php's file_get_content('a url');

The thing is if the url has '&' in it, for example

`file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/?var1=1&var2=2')`

it automatically make a requests to `www.google.com/?var1=1&amp;var2=2`

How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Could you show a little more code around the `file_get_content()` line, I suspect the error may be in a previous line.

Comment: This is happening to me as well!! is this a cronjob on godaddy by any chance?

Comment: same thing happening with me, out of 3 urls only one is producing &amp; so no way to say use curl, I want solution within this function. file_get_contents().. thank you

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the original poster of the question.  To be very specific:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=301+E.+Linwood+Avenue++Turlock%2C+CA

This requires the sensor=false variable to be passed, or the query will return BAD results from Google.  If I pass this STRING through file_get_contents, it (PHP file_get_contents) replaces the "&" with `"&amp;"` so Google doesn't like me:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=301 E. Linwood Avenue  Turlock, CA&amp;sensor=false) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
)
```

So this is the solution I came up with, using http_build_query

```
$myURL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?';   
        $options = array("address"=>$myAddress,"sensor"=>"false");
    $myURL .= http_build_query($options,'','&');

    $myData = file_get_contents($myURL) or die(print_r(error_get_last()));
```

I also include the code (thanks Marco K.) I found on the [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to use a custom function for PHP < 5:

```
if (!function_exists('http_build_query')) { 
    function http_build_query($data, $prefix='', $sep='', $key='') { 
        $ret = array(); 
        foreach ((array)$data as $k => $v) { 
            if (is_int($k) && $prefix != null) { 
                $k = urlencode($prefix . $k); 
            } 
            if ((!empty($key)) || ($key === 0))  $k = $key.'['.urlencode($k).']'; 
            if (is_array($v) || is_object($v)) { 
                array_push($ret, http_build_query($v, '', $sep, $k)); 
            } else { 
                array_push($ret, $k.'='.urlencode($v)); 
            } 
        } 
        if (empty($sep)) $sep = ini_get('arg_separator.output'); 
        return implode($sep, $ret); 
    }// http_build_query 
}//if
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try looking at the CURL libraries in PHP that would allow you to do something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mysite.com/file.php?blah=yar&test=blah");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You can then get the results from $data.

Comment: Why use cURL (which the user may not have installed on their PHP installation, as it's an extra extension) if file_get_contents should work properly? In this case it just looks like something odd is happening with URL Encoding.

Comment: cURL is a fairly common extension... and it is specifically designed for URL requests. File_get_contents is not "designed" for URLs.

Comment: I don't agree that file_get_contents was not designed for URLs. Check the manual for the function on www.php.net and you'll see that the first example actually demonstrates reading a file over HTTP. But I agree that it's purpose ends with the most simple GET requests. Anything more complex (POST, manipulating headers, uploading files, etc) is not supported. However, I wouldn't recommend using cURL as it's fairly old extension. Instead, how about looking into Zend_Http which is part of the Zend Framework and is fully OO: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html

Comment: @Janci, Yea you could use Zend. I know one of the Zend_Http adapters is Curl, and the other uses straight sockets. I've always been really happy with the curl libraries

Comment: Careful! Before PHP 5.6, file_get_contents did not verify the peer when attempting to connect over HTTPS, so it can open your app up to security vulns.

Answer (score 1):

Try replace simple quote `'` for double quote `"`:

`file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/?var1=1&var2=2")`

it seems odd, but works!

Comment: This doesn't work if your query string is set with vars:  $var1=1;   file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/?var1=$var1&var2=2") will cause the string to become html special char encoded.

Comment: Stay the same for me. Still getting the &amp;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you in fact have a string with "&amp ;". You probably can't see it because you just show the output in the browser. You should use the browsers source view to make html elements visible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely part of your PHP code.  I suspect that what you think is happening is not actually happening.

I suspect that rather than the code you posted, you are probably grabbing part of that URL from a variable, such as:

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://example.com/?$myvariable");
```

Echoing that variable to the browser may be hiding the fact that you've inadvertently encoded special characters in a previous step, because in the browser an "&amp;" is going to look like "&".

It's also possible that your file_get_contents() request is working correctly, and what you think is a problem with encoding the & sign may be a problem somewhere else - posting actual source code might help determining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's nothing wrong with using `&amp;` as field separator in query string. It is perfectly [valid](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp) and even [recommended by w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2). The problem with using `&` is that it interacts with character entity references (which has form `&xxx;`).

Also, see the note in PHP manual for [url_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function:

> Be careful about variables that
>   may match HTML entities. Things like
>   &amp, &copy and &pound are parsed by
>   the browser and the actual entity is
>   used instead of the desired variable
>   name. This is an obvious hassle that
>   the W3C has been telling people about
>   for years. PHP supports changing the argument
>   separator to the W3C-suggested
>   semi-colon through the arg_separator
>   .ini directive. Unfortunately most
>   user agents do not send form data in
>   this semi-colon separated format. A
>   more portable way around this is to
>   use `&amp;` instead of `&` as the
>   separator.

If you really don't like the `&amp;` in your URLs, I'd suggest to check the setting of [arg_separator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.output) directive in your php.ini file, although I'm not 100% sure it influences the way how file_get_contents modifies the URLs

Comment: whoever down-voted this, could you please comment on your concerns?

Comment: The problem with this post is that an ampersand is represented by &amp; in HTML. It is used only in a HTML-encoded string, e.g. in the <a href=" ... "> but *never* in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

try this config in php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

if use https url, must config

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```