# PHP : file_get_contents not working properly

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

I have a html page which sends a get request to php.
This is the code snippet in the php file

```
<?php
    // Create a stream
    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>'GET',
      )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    //echo("http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopName.aspx?token={$_GET['token']}&agencyName={$_GET['agency']}&stopName={$_GET['stopname']}");

    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $file = file_get_contents("http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopName.aspx?token={$_GET['token']}&agencyName={$_GET['agency']}&stopName={$_GET['stopname']}", false, $context);
    //$file = file_get_contents("http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopName.aspx?token=123-456-789&agencyName=SF-MUNI&stopName=The%20Embarcadero%20and%20Folsom%20St", false, $context);
    echo(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($file)));
?>
```

Developer Console Output :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopName.aspx?token=123-456-789&amp;amp;agencyName=BART&amp;amp;stopName=Powell St. (SF)): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

As you can see from the developer console output, in the url request sent there are `BART&amp;amp;stopName` amp;amp; being inserted in the url which I'm not doing. The request fails due to this. Any solution around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php file\_get\_contents and &amp;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656940/php-file-get-contents-and-amp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code, this will make sure that you're stuff is properly URI encoded.

```
$params = [
    'token' => $_GET['token'],
    'agencyName' => $_GET['agency'],
    'stopName' => $_GET['stopname']
];

$file = file_get_contents(sprintf("http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopName.aspx?%s", http_build_query($params));
echo(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($file)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$data = array('token'=>$_GET['token'],
          'stopname'=>$_GET['stopname'],
          'agency'=>$_GET['agency'],
);
$url = "http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopName.aspx?".$data;
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($file)));
```

Note: I have modified my answer base on your comment.

Comment: @PrasadShinde Checkout modified answer

Comment: It still did no work. Some issue with the concatenation but the request still contained extra params

Comment: Still extra param? I got this "<transitServiceError>Parameter Required</transitServiceError>". additional param require.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to clean out the url:

```
<?php
    // Create a stream
    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>'GET',
      )
    );



    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $url= "http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopName.aspx?";
    $query =  array(
        "token" =>$_GET['token'],
        "agencyName"=>$_GET['agency'],
        "stopName"=>$_GET['stopname']
        );

    $url = $url.http_build_query($query);
    $url = rawurldecode($url);
    print_r($url);

    $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($file)));
?>
```