# php file_get_contents($url) & turns into &amp;

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents, url-encoding, ampersand

I am trying to make a request to the coinbase api like this

```
$url = "https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=".date($format,$starting_date)."&end=".date($format,$ending_date)."&granularity=".$granularity;
```

and then I pass that in `file_get_contents($url)` but it gives me an error

file_get_contents(`https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=2015-05-07&amp;end=2015-05-08&amp;granularity=900`): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

The problem of course is when the '&' gets changed into '&'.

Comment: Are you sure this is the problem? since going directly to that url works fine.

Comment: Maybe not. but what else could be the reason that it isn't returning the file contents and instead an error.

Comment: this might answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710147/php-get-content-of-http-400-response

Comment: There seems to be a bug in PHP 7.0 causing this for valid URL strings. Switching to 7.1 resolves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need define an user agent.
Try this;

```
$url = "https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=2015-05-07&end=2015-05-08&granularity=900";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

If you still insist on using `file_get_contents` then it is still possible to use user agent;

```
$url = "https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=2015-05-07&end=2015-05-08&granularity=900";

$options = array(
    "http"=>array(
        "header"=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

For more information you can check [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) (for using headers) documentation

Comment: it dumped bool(false)

Comment: Then you have a different problem. It's OK with me. I get results with both `cURL` and `file_get_contents`

Comment: it didn't work with curl, but the edited file_get_contents,WORKED. but could you please describe what is happening.

Comment: The API expects `User Agent` to be set without setting an user agent, it simply doesn't work. I simply set user agent in order API to output a result with given parameters.

Comment: Ok. thats great. Thanks a million!

Comment: My pleasure, I wish you best of luck with your projects.

Answer (score 7):

Posting this because it worked best for me. I know it is an old question.

I found that when building the query using `http_build_query` the ampersand problem went away.

#### Example

```
$url = 'https://example.url';

// http_build_query builds the query from an array
$query_array = array (
    'search' => $string,
    'from' => $from,
    'to' => $to,
    'format' => 'json'
);

$query = http_build_query($query_array);
$result = file_get_contents($url . '?' . $query);
```

edit: just saw @joshi s answer (actually followed the link), and http_build_query is used there.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen when one of the parameters you send is not `urlencode`d.

When php sees malformed url (e,g: with spaces or other url blacklisted characters) it urlencode's the full request.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the double quotes for single quotes. It's the simplest answer listed here:

[php file_get_contents and &amp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656940/php-file-get-contents-and-amp)

The top one is more involved, but is probably a safer bet.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to :

```
$url = html_entity_decode($url);
file_get_contents($url);
```

For details on [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

**UPDATED**

Try replacing

```
& with &amp; in url as below

$url = "https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=".date($format,$starting_date)."&amp;end=".date($format,$ending_date)."&amp;granularity=".$granularity;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can revert the htmlspecialchars by using :

```
htmlspecialchars_decode();
```

try calling `file_get_contents` like so :

`file_get_contents(htmlspecialchars_decode($url));`