# Failed to open stream with file_get_contents - can access it via endpoint in browser

Tags: php, json, rest, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use Coinbase's REST API to get a list of available currencies:

Here is the endpoint - https://api.prime.coinbase.com/currencies

You can see the JSON loads when you click the link above.

```
$coinbase_coins = file_get_contents('https://api.prime.coinbase.com/currencies');
$coinbase_coins = json_decode($coinbase_coins, true);
```

Now when I try to load it with file_get_contents, I get the error "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Why is it that I can access the endpoint via browser but now with file_get_contents?

Thanks ;)

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed ?

Comment: Try setting a user-agent. That worked for me. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120211/php-file-get-contentsurl-turns-into-amp/30120589#30120589

Answer (score 0):

Could be your php runtime configuration.  allow_url_fopen needs to be set to true.

Read about it here [here](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) in the manual.

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm also using the same structure for other REST API's endpoints without issue.

Comment: Is https required?  Have you tried using http instead?

Comment: I gave that a shot but no luck unfortunately. Appreciate your input anyway :)

Comment: If I were at my computer I'd try to duplicate the problem.

Comment: probably because of https. have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https

Comment: Were you able to run their test?  If so, what were there results for the https wrapper? As far as I understand, http wrapper is suppose to handle https as well.  But my knowledge is limited here.

Comment: From php.net

Note: HTTPS is only supported when the openssl extension is enabled.

Thats worth looking into

Comment: The other Rest APIs im accessing all use https .. no issues using them. Ill look into it more today.

Comment: Very strange. Good luck. Ill try to duplicate the problem later myself.