# PHP execute a external url without redirect (background)

Tags: php, url, sms, sms-gateway

I have a API url for sending SMS and I have to execute this url once i create a new user. Using PHP how can i call the url in background?
I have tried `file_get_contents()`
My url is like this

> http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com/WebSMS/SMSAPI.php?username=hidden&password=hidden&sendername=iZycon&mobileno=8443223

While using `file_get_contents()` im getting a 'Bad request' due to the change in url where all the '**&**' got replaced using '**`&amp;`**'. this replaces the username and password which passed to the url.

And also tried some other functions like `fopen()` `curl()` . unfortunately for all this function im facing the same issue.

So which is the proper method for calling this kinda URL.?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that URL a variable you are passing to the file_get_contents? Maybe run http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php on it before

Comment: You should be able to invoke a URL with any of those methods.  How are you constructing the request?  Presumably you're doing something to HTML-encode the URL, which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: also tried decoding the url 'htmlspecialchars_decode();' etc. but '&' always changed to '&amp'

Comment: possible duplicate of [php file\_get\_contents and &amp;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656940/php-file-get-contents-and-amp)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps try executing it like so:

```
<?php    
$url = 'http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com/WebSMS/SMSAPI.php';

$fields = array(
    'username'      => "hidden",
    'password'      => "hidden",
    'sendername'    => "iZycon",
    'mobileno'      => 8443223
);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```